# Modify a YAML playbook in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, yaml

I have a delivery.yaml used by Ansible to deploy data :

```
---
  - name: Deploy to Filer on host
    hosts: host
    tasks:
      - name: Copy files
        copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} mode=0775
        with_items:
          - { src: 'data1.xml', dest: '' }
          - { src: 'data2.so', dest: '' }
          - { src: 'data3.exe', dest: '' }
          - { src: 'data4.lib', dest: '' }
```

I need to complete the "dest" value according to the data extension :

```
xml files => target1
so files => target2
exe files => target3
lib files => target4
```

How to write it ? I'm not used with groovy language. Currently, I write this but it does not work  :

```
stage('YAML test'){
            steps{
                script{
                    yamlData = readYaml file: 'delivery.yaml'
                    yamlData.tasks.with_items.find{it.src.endsWith("xml")}.dest="target1"
                    writeYaml file: 'delivery_temp.yaml', data: yamlData
                    sh "cat delivery_temp.yaml"
                }
            }
        }
```

I got this error :

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.endsWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xml]
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: What "does not work" - please be specific.

Comment: I edit my message with the specific error :
"hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.endsWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xml]"

Comment: According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_endswith.htm, the `endsWith` method belongs to the String type and not the List type. I believe your lambda iteration should initialize one variable for the key and another for the value instead of one for everything, and then you should have the correct type. Give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that your outermost data type is already a list.
So Groovy will use the implicit spread operator.  What is implied here
is:

```
yamlData*.tasks*.with_items.find{ it*.src.endWith ... }
```

So you actually want to do the transformation for each element on the
outer most level:

```
yamlData.each{ it.tasks.each { task -> task.with_items.find{it.src.endsWith("xml")}.dest="target1" } }
```

Whether the `find` here is correct depends on the data (this will only
find the first one and it will fail if there is none).  Most likely you
want `findAll` instead (which results in a list of all results and the
`.dest` assignment would still work due to the implicit spread operator).

And to get rid of the copy and paste code for
doing this for all four types (or how many there will be), you are
better off extracting the transformations out as data (e.g. a map from
suffix to target)

Comment: I try with : `yamlData.each{ it.tasks.with_items.findAll{it.src.endsWith("xml")}.dest="target1" }` but I got the same error `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.endsWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xml]`

Comment: There is another level of nesting at `tasks`. I have adjusted the answer

Comment: Nice, thank you, I understand now and it's working !